# mmap for virtual memory

Tags: c, virtual-machine, mmap

This question is going to be a bit vague since I do not exactly know what I am talking about. Bad start, I know, but let me explain.

So, I am currently writing a small virtual machine just for fun, and now I'm 
at the stage where I'm trying to create some form of heap. While researching I stumbled upon the function `mmap()`, which I've read can be used for mapping a file in the virtual address space.

But, I've recently seen it being used with the flag MAP_ANONYMOUS by multiple virtual machines to allocate memory. How is mmap used in this case?

Can it be used just like malloc if I do something like this: `mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);` (I stole that from cpython on github).

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34042915/what-is-the-purpose-of-map-anonymous-flag-in-mmap-system-call

Comment: See  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739296/malloc-vs-mmap-in-c for a very similar question.